# C# ASPNET using SQL Server Stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm currently using stored procedures but I've encountered some problems while changing stuff, it was actually working until I added the CPF field. Always when I try to register a new user I get an error:

> procedure or function has too many arguments specified

I have this procedure which register users:

```
CREATE PROC FI_SP_IncClienteV2
    @NOME          VARCHAR (50) ,
    @SOBRENOME     VARCHAR (255),
    @CPF           VARCHAR(15)  ,
    @NACIONALIDADE VARCHAR (50) ,
    @CEP           VARCHAR (9)  ,
    @ESTADO        VARCHAR (2)  ,
    @CIDADE        VARCHAR (50) ,
    @LOGRADOURO    VARCHAR (500),
    @EMAIL         VARCHAR (2079),
    @TELEFONE      VARCHAR (15) 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CLIENTES (NOME, SOBRENOME, CPF, NACIONALIDADE, CEP, ESTADO, CIDADE, LOGRADOURO, EMAIL, TELEFONE) 
      VALUES (@NOME, @SOBRENOME, @CPF, @NACIONALIDADE, @CEP, @ESTADO, @CIDADE, @LOGRADOURO, @EMAIL, @TELEFONE)

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

This piece of code is responsible for running the procedure and it's inheriting from another class:

```
internal long Incluir(DML.Cliente cliente)
{
    List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter> parametros = new List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter>();

    parametros.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Nome", cliente.Nome));
    parametros.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Sobrenome", cliente.Sobrenome));
    parametros.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("CPF", cliente.CPF));
    parametros.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Nacionalidade", cliente.Nacionalidade));
    parametros.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("CEP", cliente.CEP));
    parametros.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Estado", cliente.Estado));
    parametros.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Cidade", cliente.Cidade));
    parametros.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Logradouro", cliente.Logradouro));
    parametros.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Email", cliente.Email));
    parametros.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Telefone", cliente.Telefone));

    DataSet ds = base.Consultar("FI_SP_IncClienteV2", parametros);
    long ret = 0;
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        long.TryParse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString(), out ret);

    return ret;
}

internal DataSet Consultar(string NomeProcedure, List<SqlParameter> parametros)
{
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(stringDeConexao);

    comando.Connection = conexao;
    comando.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comando.CommandText = NomeProcedure;
    foreach (var item in parametros)
        comando.Parameters.Add(item);

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    conexao.Open();

    try
    {               
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    finally
    {
        conexao.Close();
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: I think that the parameters name have to be exakt mening. uppercase text. and also try adding `@` at the begining as i dont know if `SqlParameter` add it automaticly

Comment: I guess it does, I've been using it like that for a while. Just added new Field.

Comment: You don't need "@" and they are not case sensitive.

Comment: Are you sure you have modified the stored procedure in the right database on the right server?

Comment: Yes, I'm using localDB.

Comment: Your code looks good... the number of parameters in stored procedure and in C# code are the same. Names also the same. The only possibility is that the code is trying to execute the old version of procedure... this can happen only if the procedure is not updated properly or you have update the procedure on a different database... You can recheck the stored procedure on the server and also verify the database server and db name in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

So I went over everything on the database as Chetan Ranpariya recommended and I noticed that even though I had made changes on my Stored procedure I hadn't updated it on the database.